# LNK1104: cannot open libpjproject-i386-Win32-vc14-Debug-Static.lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors, sip, pjsip

I am using Visual Studio 19 to compile a Microsip C++ code on 2015(v140).I integrated additional libraries like pjmedia,pjnath,pjsua,pjsip,etc.But i am facing this error.I think I have made a mistake in integrating the pjproject sip libraries and microsip libraries.Help?

Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'libpjproject-i386-Win32-vc14-Debug-Static.lib'

Comment: PJProject has several build options Release-Static one of them.

When I chosen Release-Static, my problem was solved. You should also find Debug-Static then it will be build to the lib directory.

Answer (score 0):

Add the path of the library files to the library path.

Right click the project and go to `Properties->Linker->Additional Library` directories. Add the path to this list

Answer (score 0):

`libpjproject-i386-Win32-vc14-Debug-Static.lib` - this is debug library of pj-project. Looks like your MicroSIP project tries to find it, but without success. I suggest you should build it(mentioned library) from pjsip-solution and copy builded library from pjsip-solution to your MicroSIP solution.

For more details about Error LNK1104, I suggest you could refer to the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1104?view=vs-2019).